# User registration approval based on role selected

Tags: user-roles, user-registration

On my site I've got two types of users, Subscribers and Partners.

I've used [Cimy User Extra Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/) to add additional fields to the registration form. I've also used a plugin called [WP Roles at Registration](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-roles-at-registration/). This plugin adds a drop down box on the registration form so when a user registers they can pick their own role.

What I want to be able to do is, if a user selects Subscriber as their role they become registered and can use their account as normal. However if a user selects Partner, the account needs to be reviewed and approved by an editor before they can use it, to ensure they are actually a Partner.

The reason I say it needs to be approved by an editor is because the people who will be using it won't have access to an admin account.

It also needs to send an email to an editor to tell them the account needs to be approved and possibly send an email to the user once their account has been approved.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kept using Cimy User Extra Fields but got rid of WP Roles at Registration and left it as a manual process. User register as normal and then manually change a persons role.

Answer (score 0):

Without writing a custom plugin, I think your best bets would be to either:

1) use something like gravity forms and have the user start as subscriber, but then enter request to be a partner (using a GF form).  GF can send notifications on forms to admin.  Admin then upgrades the user's role.

2) use a interim role like "request to be partner".  New users get notified to admin.
"request for partner" users reviewed and upgrade to "partner".

Do editors by default have capability to manage users ? I suspect maybe not.  In which case you could use a role manager plugin (justin tadlock members plugin for eg) to add manage_users to the editor role (which would probably mean an editor could make themselves an Admin? hmm maybe not a good idea? ....)